# MySQL won't insert variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a MySQL statement to insert information to a table:

```
 $insert = "INSERT INTO `vle`.`files`
               (`id`, `time`, `fileLocation`, `title`, `user`)

               VALUES (
                   NULL,
                   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),

                   '".mysql_real_escape_string($putFile)."',
                   '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."',
                   '".$user."'
               )";
```

Everything inserts correctly except for the `$user` variable which echos out but doesn't get inserted and the same goes for `$putFile`. Is there anything in this MySQL statement that I am doing wrong?

Thanks

full code here

```
    <?php require_once('Connections/localhost.php');
    include('pageCheck.php');
    include('adminCheck.php');

    function saveFile(){
        global $_FILES, $_POST;

        $insert = "INSERT INTO `vle`.`files` 
(`id`, `time`, `fileLocation`, `title`, `user`) 
VALUES (NULL, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '".mysql_real_escape_string($putFile)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."', '".$user."')";

        mysql_query($insert);

        var_dump($insert);
    }

    $putFile = "files/".basename($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'], $putFile)){
        saveFile();
        echo"File has been uploaded, Redirecting to file list now...";
        //echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=dashboard.php'>";

        }else{

        echo"Unable to upload file, Returning to dashboard...";
        //echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=dashboard.php'>";  

        }


     ?>
```

$user us defined in pageCheck.php

Comment: `var_dump($insert);` and show here (and since now **always** check the real sql generated, not the source php code)

Comment: string(122) "INSERT INTO `vle`.`files` (`id`, `time`, `fileLocation`, `title`, `user`) VALUES (NULL, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '', 'blah3', '')"

Comment: There's your problem, `$putFile` and `$user` are empty (or undefined). [Enabling error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10135983/283366) will yield more information.

Comment: im a bit of a n00b at this, thanks

Comment: Do you have a mysql connection open before calling `mysql_real_escape_string()`? [Docs](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string): Note: A MySQL connection is required before using `mysql_real_escape_string()` otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used.

Comment: could it be a page flow issue? If i move the code down the page would that help?

Comment: Can you show a more complete sample of your code, preferably where you set `$user` and actually run the query?

Comment: I Think that could be the problem, i'll try selecting the db :)

Comment: @TheScrumMeister That would explain `$putFile` but not `$user`. Nice comment though

Comment: Add `$putFile` & `$user` to the globals

Comment: @TheScrumMeister That's a terrible idea :(

Comment: @phil quick fix vs full answer...

Comment: i take it adding them to globals is a bad thing? Did it your way @phil, Thank you both for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is a scoping one. Within your `saveFile()` function, `$user` and `$putFile` are not in scope.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

You should consider passing them as arguments, eg

```
function saveFile($user, $file, $title) {
    // etc
}

saveFile($user, $putFile, $_POST['title']);
```